# HTML export from LibreOffice Writer

Tags: html, libreoffice

I want to export formatted text from LibreOffice to HTML. By default, it is exported with lot of inline styles.

Is it possible to keep the semantics of the formatting (`<p>`, `<ul>`, `<h2>` and so on), but get rid of the inline styles?

For example, I get 
`<p lang="de-DE" class="western" align="justify" style="margin-bottom: 0in">`

What I want is just: `<p>`

Thanks and regards,

Adriana

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused as to what you are trying to accomplish? What are you exporting from libreOffice? Is it something you could create in notepad or gedit?

Answer (score 1):

Since years I second your question. I'd like to be able to export some document to a clean html-format, either to process further on or to just use as is.

Today I send an enhancement request to libreoffice to get an export-to for every save-to format. Since html is in the save-as format, it wil end up in the export-to format. With this export to html, we can ask the question for alternate html variants like 'clean html' and optionally create an html-book with one html-page per chapter (html-books).

btw: My reason for export-to for all save-as formats is because I'd like to keep the current format in the editor. after a save-as the editor format is changed to the new format. Then it is accepted to require all formatting to keep the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an automated HTML converter type situation you kinda just have to take what you get and modify it yourself. The reason it has all of the styling is because it needs that to make the exported html file look like the libreoffice file. From what you said, it looks like you don't want all of the style from libreoffice and you just want it to look like a barebones html document. These defeats the purpose of using libreoffice to export the html rather than just creating the html document from scratch from a bare bones text editor or and IDE. If the document you are trying to convert is already a libreoffice document, I would recommend just copying and pasting the sections you want into a barebones document in the tags you want.

Comment: Specifically, the question is about preserving just the semantics, not the formatting. We don't know why or how the text had become a formatted text, but LibreOffice is to be used to produce just structured text. It isn't very good at doing this. "Save as HTML" might be better than "Export HTML", since the latter also tries to preserve kerning and such, using lots of additional text not expressing semantics as asked.